# htaccess subdomain rewrite without a redirect

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

Using htaccess Rewrite, I want my url http://*.phoneataxi.com/ (where * is a wildcard, excluding 'www') to show in the address bar as is but get information from http://*.phoneataxi.com/test.php?c=*.

I have tried so many different things but nothing is doing exactly what I need. Most examples are redirecting the subdomain to the '/test.php' file in the address bar which I don't want to do.

I'm trying not to have to create individial subdomains and subdomain folders within my webroot.

Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I use this `htaccess` file to make Apache act as a proxy for another host:

```
IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ghost\.pileborg\.se$
RewriteRule (.*) http://vps.pileborg.se/ghost/$1 [P]
</IfModule>
```

It causes all access to http://ghost.pileborg.se/ to be "redirected" to http://vps.pileborg.se/ghost/.

Answer (score 0):

## UPDATE (2020)

Some of the answers regarding this topic is very old and no longer work as expected.
After searching for hours on something that actually works, this is what I came up with; edit as you see fit:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([a-z0-9]+)\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=BASE:%1]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{ENV:BASE}/index.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{ENV:BASE}/index.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}/index.html [L,NC,QSA]
```

### Breakdown

Make sure that the `rewrite` module is installed and enabled on your host

- first we turn the `rewrite` engine on and set the path-base
- then isolate the **subdomain** - any letters/numbers before the first dot
- set a variable in this runtime environment that contains the **subdomain**
- check if the subdomain folder and index-file exists
- if it ***does*** exist -then use that file as the request-handler (no redirect)
- if it does ***not*** exist then the request carries on normally

### Flags

The flags used here are explained [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html), but the ones used above are quite simple:

- `[L]`  Last rule, ignore the rest
- `[NC]` No Case, no uppercase/lowercase restrictions
- `[QSA]` I remember this as "Query String Attach" :D